# How can I generate a link to a resource not in the WebAPI routing table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to make a Virtual directory relative link to some unknown (to WebAPI) resource form an `ApiController`.

Example:

> http://some/path/webapi/does/not/know

The WebAPI Url helper seems to be tightly coupled with Routing and does not have a Content() method like the MVC variant.  I'm trying to avoid using any non-mockable HTTP context information to make this call (such as `HttpContext.Current`).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried to just create a `System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper` in your API controller in order to use the `Content` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can always do,

var urlBuilder =
    new System.UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
        {
            Path = "webapi/does/not/know"
        };

var uri = urlBuilder.Uri

In that way, you don't need to rely on the UrlHelper. The base url is inferred from the current request.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options you can try:

1. [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx)
2. Create a `System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper` in your API controller